# How to get base64 of image in React Native

Tags: base64, react-native

I'm using react native image picker and image resizer to pick and then resize an image. How do I get the base64 of the image once it has been resized?

```
ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(imagepicker_options, (response) => {
  ImageResizer.createResizedImage(response.uri, 550, null, 'JPEG', 100).then((resizedImageUri) => {
    //get base64 of image
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

https://libraries.io/npm/react-native-asset-library-to-base64

```
ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(imagepicker_options, (response) => {
  ImageResizer.createResizedImage(response.uri, 550, null, 'JPEG', 100).then((resizedImageUri) => {
      //get base64 of image, uri is link to asset-library://
      ReadImageData.readImage(uri, (imageBase64) => {
    console.log(imageBase64);
    });
  });
});
```

you might also want to read this if you haven't https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1158

Comment: What about Android?

Comment: [https://github.com/xfumihiro/react-native-image-to-base64](https://github.com/xfumihiro/react-native-image-to-base64)

Comment: There is an issue said that it does not work on Android  0.49. https://github.com/xfumihiro/react-native-image-to-base64/issues/11. Please update it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `imagepicker_options` provides a way to resize.
You can pass `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` on options.

The code:

```js
const imagepicker_options = {
  mediaType: 'photo',
  maxWidth: 550,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    cameraRoll: false,
    path: 'images',
  },
}
ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(imagepicker_options, (response) => {
  //get base64 of image
  const base64 = response.data
});
```